# How to pass java.net.Socket to a C++ DLL function waiting for `BoostSocket.assign(tcp::v4(), nativeSocketFromJava);`

Tags: java, c++, sockets, dll, shared-libraries

So I wonder is it possible and how to pass socket from java to some DLL library waiting for native for this OS socket? Could any one provide an example? Is it anyhow possible to use org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first - we need to get a file descriptor of `java.net.Socket`. That is possible to do using reflection mechanism. The idea is to get access to `java.io.FileDescriptor` on the `java.net.SocketImpl` and then get a native socket descriptor. See [`DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Platform/windows/java/net/DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java.htm) for code snippets (this method is also pointed out by Zoran Regvart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207881/using-a-java-socket-from-jni-c-code/2211255#2211255)).

Another method is to use JNI, as discussed [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t140746-passing-java-socket-fd-to-c-hack.html), here is an example:

```
static int getFd(JNIEnv *env, jobject sock)
{
    JNIEnv e = *env;
    jclass clazz;
    jfieldID fid;
    jobject impl;
    jobject fdesc;

    /* get the SocketImpl from the Socket */
    if (!(clazz = e->GetObjectClass(env,sock)) ||
        !(fid = e->GetFieldID(env,clazz,"impl","Ljava/net/SocketImpl;")) ||
        !(impl = e->GetObjectField(env,sock,fid))) return -1;

    /* get the FileDescriptor from the SocketImpl */
    if (!(clazz = e->GetObjectClass(env,impl)) ||
        !(fid = e->GetFieldID(env,clazz,"fd","Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;")) ||
        !(fdesc = e->GetObjectField(env,impl,fid))) return -1;

    /* get the fd from the FileDescriptor */
    if (!(clazz = e->GetObjectClass(env,fdesc)) ||
        !(fid = e->GetFieldID(env,clazz,"fd","I"))) return -1;

    /* return the descriptor */
    return e->GetIntField(env,fdesc,fid);
}
```

I also suppose you are talking about Boost.Asio's TCP socket. If so, then you have to associate a native socket with Asio's socket object using [`assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/assign.html) method.

Be aware that this solution may not work for certain Java implementations as it is using internal details of the implementation that is not guaranteed to stay the same. Plus, make sure the is no concurrency (i.e. Java is not trying to read from the same socket descriptor in parallel) etc. In other words - use at your own risk.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: +1 I really like JNI method. Will it work on windows? And if yes how? It seemed for me socket was not just an int on windows...

Comment: That should work on Windows, I think. At least for Open JDK (check out sources here, they use `int` - http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/). HANDLE seems to be a socket descriptor that fits in `int`, so upcasting it to HANDLE (if that is 64 bit pointer, for example) should be OK.

Comment: @Kabumbus: Asio, I think, expects `HANDLE`, Win32 works with `SOCKET`, JDK treats that as `int`. It seems that they all are compatible (if not just typedefs for `int`). It doesn't hurt to try, I am pretty confident that will work out.